# ssh connection closed on connect

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal

In terminal on Mac OS enter

```
ssh login@xx.xx.xx.xx
```

after that password.

instantly see it

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab120.6 i686)
* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
Last login: Tue Nov 29 14:38:45 2016 from yy.yy.yy.yy
Connection to xx.xx.xx.xx closed.
```

why connection was closed?

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the user (e.g. `login`) you are using has permissions to access ssh over the server.

Its also possible that there is an `exit 0` in your `.bash_profile`.  This will cause the session to close immediately after logging in. 
You can try this command to remove the it: `ssh david@0.0.0.1 sed -i '/exit\ 0/d' .bashrc .bash_profile .profile .login`

Answer (score 1):

Use `ssh -v login@xx.xx.xx.xx` and check the output for hints regarding the connection drop.